# customize styling on Twitter embedded tweet

Tags: css, twitter, tweets

I am trying to simply add some css to my embedded tweets on my site

This seems like it ought to be ridiculously easy, and it was actually working, then suddenly stopped. My code is:

```
<blockquote class="twitter-tweet" style="background-color: #E1CFB9 !important;"><p>People scoff at emoticons. How else do you convey body language in a 140char tweet with a perfect stranger? More :-) == Less flame</p>&mdash; Jeff Madsen (@codebyjeff) <a href="https://twitter.com/codebyjeff/status/263808956697292801" data-datetime="2012-11-01T01:05:31+00:00">November 1, 2012</a></blockquote>

<script src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>

<style>
.twitter-tweet-rendered{
    padding-left: 20px;
    background-color: #E1CFB9 !important;
    border: 1px solid #77947E !important;
}
.standalone-tweet{
    background-color: #E1CFB9 !important;           
}
</style>
```

The only trick involved last time was to call the js file to let it re-render the blockquote, then apply the css on top.

No idea what changed, but the .standalone-tweet background no longer applies, and every css, javascript, delayed javascript, whatever trick I can think of will not work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this instead?

```
<script src="http://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

Comment: why would that be different? the js is obviously being found & called correctly

Comment: For some weird reasons, I have to do this on my machine to get it to work. I have no explanation, other than my own trail and error!

Comment: interesting...I'll give it a try later. certainly can't explain why it would

Comment: gave it a shot - no affect.thanx anyway

Comment: I tried your snippet again, without that change, it doesn't work for me either. When I add `http:` at the beginning, it works just fine!

Comment: I'll have to ask what browser, OS, etc - cuz on Windows 8, FF or Chrome, absolutely no joy. You sure you are using the above snippet, and the tweet is turning to different colors in the full block?

Comment: I am using MacOS, tried it with Safari and Chrome, both worked. The only thing is that I get this image: http://i48.tinypic.com/10mt2ma.png, I have to select all and deselect and then i see it in full: http://tinypic.com/r/15o9jxy/6

Comment: lol - it is the white part I am trying to make beige. Yours isn't working correctly either :-)

Comment: Oh ok, i got the impression that NOTHING works for you. Anyways, sorry I couldn't help